# When did D&D 4e get racial ability bonus choice?

Tags: dnd-4e, errata

I noticed recently a handful of D&D 4E races have been [updated](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updatesarchive), to have one *fixed* ability bonus and one *choice*, between two other stats.

*When did that happen? What was the reasoning behind this?*

I also noticed some of the races don't have any choice, *is there a reason for this?*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It all started with Player's Handbook 3, which offered alternative, non-fixed ability score bonuses for its new races. This new design was then adopted as the default and included in subsequent books.

Some of the "core" races of Player's Handbook and Player's Handbook 2 have then been updated in the Essentials line books (Heroes of the Fallen Lands + Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms), at least as far as these books contained the mentioned races.

Later, on March 14th 2011, a [publicly available Dragon article](https://web.archive.org/web/20151107013502/http://archive.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/drag/201103abilities) added alternative ability score bonuses for all remaining races and provided an overview of the ability modifiers of all playable races.